# Are there any good books for GameMaker:Studio?

Tags: game-maker

I'm just wondering if there are any good books for the GameMaker:Studio software?

I want to using it to prototype my projects and will be travelling for the next few days so I thought it might be a good time to familiarize myself with it. I see that there are a ton of tutorials online, but I won't have internet for most of my travels so I'm really looking for an offline resource, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have really enjoyed "The GameMakers Apprentice." When you finish that one, "The GameMakers Companion" goes deeper into GML.

Neither book is GameMaker studio specific, but the core functionality hasn't really changed.

Answer (score 1):

A quick search on Amazon would help you out, but if you're looking for first hand opinions, the only one I've read, but do recommend is [The Game Maker's Apprentice: Game Development for Beginners](http://amzn.com/1590596153).

Comment: Alright thanks, I did see that one, but wasn't sure if they were GM:Studio specific or just game makers (as a profession), I will definitely check it out.